# how to append items to existing json files when using scrapy

Tags: json, scrapy, web-crawler

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o spidername.json -t json
```

this is the command I used to crawl items and save them to existing files. but it doesn't work.

i have this error.

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 40 column 254 (char 10597)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: What do  you mean by _"doesn't work"_? What do you see? What do you expect instead?

Comment: added the error

Comment: Scrapy does not preserve correct JSON format when appending (Scrapy simply writes a new JSON array, after the previous one). You can use jsonlines (`.jl`), where each line is an individual JSON object.